# Retain object through UIAlertView/UIActionView dialogs

Tags: cocoa-touch, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I'm working on a local (to the method) custom object and need to display a dialog (UIActionSheet or UIAlertView) to the user. What's the best way to get access to same object when delegate is called after user interacts with the dialog? Any Cocoa tricks besides adding another instance variable to current class?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use ["Associated Objects"](http://blog.andymatuschak.org/post/173646741/your-new-friends-obj-c-associated-objects). (but [you can't test it in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916130/objcsetassociatedobject-unavailable-in-iphone-simulator).)