# Can I tag a UIColor?

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

Can I tag a UIColor that is constantly changing values for easy access from methods?

Comment: Clarify please. There's no tag property in UIColor, like in UIView. If you want a color object that's readily available to many methods, just place it in a member variable of type UIColor*.

Answer (score 2):

As of iPhone SDK 3.1, you can use `objc_setAssociatedObject`. You'd do something like:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(myColor, infoObject, &keyObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Note 1: the value must be an object. You can't set an integer as the value.

To retrieve the value:

```
id aTag = objc_getAssociatedObject(myColor, &keyObject);
```

Note 2: the keyObject must exactly *the same object* that you used when setting the value. It won't work if you send in another object with the same value.

If you later want to release the tag value:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(myColor, nil, &keyObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

(Due to a bug this doesn't work in the iPhone simulator. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916130/objcsetassociatedobject-unavailable-in-iphone-simulator) for more info.)

You can also read [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/5-key-value-coding-approaches-in-cocoa.html) which touches on using this method for storing keys.

Note: I'm not saying this is the best way of handling the problem. As the Objective-C programming guide states, associated objects are mainly intended for situations where

> you do not have access to the source
>   code for the class, or if for
>   binary-compatibility reasons you
>   cannot alter the layout of the object.

Read all about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html).