# Remove a UIPanGestureRecognizer after add it to view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a view and I want to enable a user to draw on it after tab a `UIButton`, I have do this using`UIPanGestureRecognizer` , add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` this view after `UIButton` touch but the issue is how I can remove this `UIPanGestureRecognizer` after I done my drawing and re-touch the `UIButton` ??

Answer (score 3):

UIView has a method called

```
- (void)removeGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

alternatively, you can disable the UIGestureRecognizer temporarily by removing its callback using the method

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

Comment: But ho I can detect if the object has recognizer or not ?
and from Where I can call removeTarget ?

Comment: You can get the recognizers associated with a UIView through its gestureRecognizers property. You can call remove target on the UIGestureRecognizer you want to disable.

Comment: but if I have many recognizers how I can get the specific one from gestureRecognizers ?

Comment: You need to keep a reference to that recognizer so that you can check against it, or, if you have only one UIPanGestureRecognizer, you can check them until you find a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple pan gesture recognizers for a view, you can tag a specific one with an associated object.

[What is objc_setAssociatedObject() and in what cases should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909412/what-is-objc-setassociatedobject-and-in-what-cases-should-it-be-used)

So at the top of your .m file, you'd put

```
static char overviewKey;
```

then right before you add your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view, you'd tag it with a string.

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(panGesture, &overviewKey, @"pan gesture for drawing", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

[someView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

When you want to delete the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, you'd go through all the gesture recognizers in that view, find the one with the string, and delete it.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in someView) {

  NSString *gestureTag= objc_getAssociatedObject(gesture, &overviewKey);


  if (gestureTag==nil) {

    continue;

   }

  if ([gestureTag isEqual:@"pan gesture for drawing"]) {

    [ someView removeGestureRecognizer:gesture ];

  }   
}
```