# Easier way to check for each bool before executing a method?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there an easier, less copy/paste way of achieving the same thing as the code below? What is the best way?

```
if (self.title.selectedSegmentIndex !=-1)
{
    [self.form setValue:[self.title titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.title.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:@"titleKey"];
}
if (self.author.selectedSegmentIndex !=-1)
{
    [self.form setValue:[self.author titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.author.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:@"authorKey"];
}
if (self.description.selectedSegmentIndex !=-1)
{
    [self.form setValue:[self.description titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.description.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:@"descriptionKey"];
}
etc....
```

**Edit**:
sorry its not a bool if statement (I believe I need this check though, otherwise it will crash when no segment is selected when trying to get the title from the index)

I feel like I have a lot of repetitive checking with these if statements and dont know a better way, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if you've created your properties correctly, you can use `[self valueForKey:@"title"]` instead of `self.title`. Then it could be as simple as looping through an array of keys.

Comment: @Cyrille Exactly, and that way, it would be something like `for (NSString *key in keysArray) { id val = [self valueForKey:key]; if (val) [self.form setValue:val forKey:key]; }`

Comment: @Cyrille Im sorry, what do you mean made my properties correctly?

Comment: this is a way to do it, but idk if it makes it easier or less convoluted 
NSArray* segmentThingies = @[self.title, self.author, self.description];
NSArray* key = @[@"titleKey", @"authorKey", @"descriptionKey"];

for ( NSInteger i = 0; i < [segmentThingies count]; i++ ) {
UISegmentedControl* segment = (UISegmentedControl*)[segmentThingies objectAtIndex:i] selectedSegmentIndex];
NSString* keyString = [key objectAtIndex:i]; 
if ([segment selectedSegmentIndex] != -1) {
[self.form setValue:[segment titleForSegmentAtIndex:segment.selectSegmentIndex] forKey:key];
}
}

Comment: might be better if you copy paste that x.x didn't think it was that long

Comment: it might also be better if you put it as an answer so I could actually read it and accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several approaches to this kind of thing. (None of the code here has been tested or even compiled.)

The most obvious is a simple method:

```
- (void)setFormValueFromSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)seg forKey:(NSString *)key {
  if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex !=-1) {
    [self.form setValue:[seg titleForSegmentAtIndex:seg.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:key];
  }
}
```

Now your code simplifies to:

```
[self setFormValueFromSegmentedControl:self.title forKey:@"titleKey"];
[self setFormValueFromSegmentedControl:self.author forKey:@"authorKey"];
...
```

Personally, I like this because it's so simple and obvious to read with a minimum of magic. But there are other solutions if even that block got unwieldy.

You can do something like @Cyrille and @H2CO3 are suggesting:

```
for (NSString *key in [@"title", @"author", ...]) {
  UISegmentedControl *seg = [self valueForKey:key];
  if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex != -1) {
    NSString *formKey = [key stringByAppendingString:@"Key"];
    [self.form setValue:[seg titleForSegmentAtIndex:seg.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:formKey];
  }
}
```

You could also use a `tag` on the control to indicate which form key it applies to (you can configure tags in IB or using `setTag:` in code). So `title` would have a tag of 0, `author` would have a tag of 1, etc.

```
NSArray *formKeyForTag = @[@"titleKey", @"authorKey", ...];
for (UISegmentedControl *seg = [... IBOutletCollection of controls ...]) {
  if (seg.selectedSegmentIndex != -1) {
    NSString *formKey = formKeyForTag[seg.tag];
    [self.form setValue:[seg titleForSegmentAtIndex:seg.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:formKey];
  }
```

Or you could add an associated object to the segmented control, pointing to the form key. See [What is objc_setAssociatedObject() and in what cases should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909412/what-is-objc-setassociatedobject-and-in-what-cases-should-it-be-used) for more on that. (I happen to love associated objects…)

Or you could use an `NSDictionary` to keep the mappings.

So lots of options. But I kind of like the simple method at the top. It's the most obvious.

Comment: Wow thank you for such a complete answer, I like the first one, it keeps things minimal and simple.

Comment: Rob is great. Trust him ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
@protocol ObjectsWithSegmentAtIndex <NSObject>

@property (assign, atomic) NSInteger selectedSegmentIndex;

@end
```

.h

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject    
@property (assign, atomic) id<ObjectsWithSegmentAtIndex> title;
@property (assign, atomic) id<ObjectsWithSegmentAtIndex> description;
...
@property (assign, atomic) Form* form;
@end
```

.m

```
NSString* KeyForValue (id<ObjectsWithSegmentAtIndex> value) {
    return [value description]; // example, not to be used this way
}

+(void) fillForm:(Form*)form withValues:(NSArray*) values {
    for (id<ObjectsWithSegmentAtIndex> value in values) {
        [self fillForm:form withValue:value forKey:KeyForValue(value)];
    }
}

+(void) fillForm:(Form*)form withValue:(id<ObjectsWithSegmentAtIndex>)value forKey:(id<NSCopying>)key {
    if (value.selectedSegmentIndex != kUndefinedSegmentIndex) {
        [form setValue:[value titleForSegmentAtIndex:value.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:key];
    }
}
```