# Associated objects in Swift, does global key actually produce specific instances?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

To have an associated object in Swift, you simply use a memory address as a handle, and then use the objc calls.

The usual example code you can google everywhere is:

```
var keyA:UInt8 = 0
var keyB:UInt8 = 0
extension UIViewController {

    var aoAA: String? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &keyA) as? String }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &keyA, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
    var aoBB: String? {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &keyB) as? String }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &keyB, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
}
```

this works fine,

```
class Thing: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aoAA = "this is a"
        print("...... \(aoAA)")
        aoBB = "this is b"
        print("...... \(aoBB)")
        aoAA = "changed A"
        print("...... \(aoAA) \(aoBB)")
        aoBB = "changed B"
        print("...... \(aoAA) \(aoBB)")
        aoAA = aoBB
        print("...... \(aoAA) \(aoBB)")
        }
```

**But wait...**

The handles, keyA and keyB, **are global to the whole project**.

When you use aoAA and aoBB in **different** UIViewController, how can it possibly be that aoAA and aoBB act as properties specific to that instance?

Surely there is only "one" aoAA everywhere in the project?

ie, aoAA is a global - just as the handle keyA is a global?

My testing seemed to show that they *are* independent variables, specific to different instances of different UIViewControllers, but that seems barmy.

How can each instance of `aoAA` possibly be different - it's using the same global handle?

Comment: u pass a reference for a "self" in each call, so it sets the associated object to your UIViewController instance

Comment: hi @orest ... thanks ... but then it uses &keyA in the call.  there is only one "&keyA" in the entire build of the app.  ?

Comment: Yep, it uses an address of keyA, address should be unique for the keyA during all the application is running

Comment: Ah, so say the key value is "1234".  Do you mean, it uses BOTH the object value as a key ("self" for us) AND the key as a key ("1234") each time it is called?  So the "key" it uses is some combination of BOTH the key ("1234") and the object (the various "self" in our example).  Is that right?

Comment: Hey @JoeBlow, I always seem to be changing your [swift3] tags to [swift] tags – note that the [swift3] tag is only for questions directly related to *changes* in the language as a result of Swift 3, whereas [swift] is for general language questions (as per their respective tag wikis). This question will be just as relevant when Swift 4 comes around :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Objective-C's concept of "associated objects" lets you connect one "target" object instance with one "source" object instance. It's a unidirectional association where only the source knows the target:

[image: Associated Objects with source and target instances]

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(source, key, target, ...)
```

The association uses a key to be able to connect and distinguish any number of associated objects with one source. The keys must obviously be different—but just for **one** source instance.

Because you have to provide both the key and the source instance to retrieve the associated object, it's not necessary to use really unique keys. The implementation of `objc_***AssociatedObject` can form a process-unique key by combining the instance pointer and the key.

So for your example, yes, both `aoAA` and `aoBB` will return individual values per each `UIViewController` instance, even though `keyA` and `keyB` are global.

To be absolutely clear, you *do* need *different* keys for *each* associated object in a given extension. So, `aoAA` and `aoBB` each need their own key, as shown in the example code (to wit, the pointers to `keyA` and `keyB`). But as is asked in the question it's correct have only *one* key for *each* associated object, no matter how many conforming classes the extension is used in.

Comment: say @NikolaiRuhe,  i did add one clarifying point to your perfect answer - feel free to unwind, edit, etc as always

Comment: No reason, I like it :)