# What's the C++ equivalent of the objc_setAssociatedObject/objc_getAssociatedObject?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, binding

Is there anything in **C++11** STL that is equivalent or similar to [`objc_setAssociatedObject/objc_getAssociatedObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909412/what-is-objc-setassociatedobject-and-in-what-cases-should-it-be-used) in **Objective-C** ?

If not then is there any way by which i can achive the same behaviour in C++ ?

Comment: Why not use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: There is no equivalent in C++. Objective C objects seem to effectively be a `map<string, property>`. C++ objects don't even have to exist at runtime. `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` directly access that underlying map (if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is nothing equivalent to `obj_setAssociatedObject`.

You can get close with a static `std::unordered_map`, but the really difficult bit is ensuring that deleting the owning object deletes the associated object.  If you don't need that, or you can modify the owning object code to have it's own map, then you should be fine.

If you *do* need to delete an associated object when the owning object is deleted, *and* you can't alter the code of the associated object, then we need more details of your application to make sensible suggestions (I suggest asking another question rather than changing this one).