# How to add properties in a category of NSURLRequest and implement getter and setter?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can we add properties in a category of NSURLRequest and implement getter in NSURLRequest and setter in NSMutableURLRequest?

What I want to do is set some custom properties in NSMutableURLRequest and load that in UiWebView. I want that all the request from UIWebView thereon whether NSMutableURLRequest or NSURLRequest have those custom properties and I can access them in a custom NSURLProtocol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instance Variables for Objective C Categories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146183/instance-variables-for-objective-c-categories)

Comment: I am aware of these solutions but they don't work. What I understand URL Loading system will create a deep copy of NSMutableURLRequest to create new requests. But when it copies will these new properties get copied to new instances? From my experiments it doesn't. I can override copy and make it work but looking for more elegant solution here.

Comment: @Salil are you able to find out a better way? I observed that the original NSURLRequest object is not passed on to NSURLProtocol by the url loading system and hence whatever additional properties I set are not passed on.

Comment: I haven't found any but had the similar issue what you are facing

Answer (score 0):

> How can we add properties in a category of NSURLRequest and implement getter in NSURLRequest and setter in NSMutableURLRequest?

Just you would do it for any other class...

```
@interface NSURLRequest (MyCategory)

@property (nonatomic, assign) int foo;

@end


@implementation NSURLRequest (MyCatgeory)

- (int)foo
{
    return 42;
}

- (void)setFoo:(int)f
{
    otherVar = f;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra properties to NSURLRequest is a special case implemented like this:

NSMutableURLRequest+JSONBody.h

```
@interface NSMutableURLRequest (JSONBody)

@property (nullable, copy, setter=mhf_setJSONBody:) id mhf_JSONBody;

@end
```

NSMutableURLRequest+JSONBody.m

```
@implementation NSMutableURLRequest (JSONBody)

-(id)mhf_JSONBody{
    return [NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(mhf_JSONBody)) inRequest:self];
}

-(void)mhf_setJSONBody:(id)JSONBody{
    [NSURLProtocol setProperty:JSONBody forKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(mhf_JSONBody)) inRequest:self];
}

@end
```

Doing it this way instead of via associated objects allows copying to work!