# Subclass CBPeripheral not casting to correct type

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a Class that is a subclass of `CBPeripheral`. This is so I can add additional properties to the `CBPeripheral`.

In the centralManager delegate method `didDiscoverPeripheral` I cast the discovered peripheral to my own subclass of `CBPeripheral` and then attempt to set my property.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    SCPCBPeripheral *discoveredPeripheral = (SCPCBPeripheral *)peripheral;
    [discoveredPeripheral setCoreBluetoothManager:self];
}
```

Sadly this will not cast to a `SCPCBPeripheral` and errors saying "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Would anyone know why this is happening?

If anyone is wondering this is my .h of the SCPCBPeripheral

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@class SCPCoreBluetoothCentralManager;

@interface SCPCBPeripheral : CBPeripheral

@property (nonatomic, strong) SCPCoreBluetoothCentralManager *coreBluetoothManager;

@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That object is created by something else that doesn't know about or use your subclass, and casting doesn't change the actual type of the instance. To change the class, you will need to copy/recreate the peripheral as your custom subclass (by writing `+[SCPCBPeripheral peripheralWithPeripheral:]`, e.g.)

Your other alternative is to add the methods and properties directly to `CBPeripheral` using a category rather than a subclass. There are two things to note about this approach. First, you cannot add ivars with a category, although [there are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146183/instance-variables-for-objective-c-categories?lq=1). Second, the methods you add will be added to *all* instances of the class; you should use a prefix on your additions to avoid name collisions.

Comment: Tell a lie, I really do like being able to go [peripheral connect] so I have added a property to a category using `<objc/runtime.h>` and `objc_setAssociatedObject`

Answer (score 3):

You can't just cast the `CBPeripheral` to your custom class. Casting it to that class won't force the real object to know how to respond to your custom methods. You should instead create a custom init method and store the `CBPeripheral` inside of your `SPCBPeripheral` instance. And from then on you should be using the `SPCBPeripheral` methods and the object will actually know how to respond (since it is actually of that type).

What you actually need to implement should look something like this:

```
SPCBPeripheral *peripheral = [[SPCBPeripheral alloc]initWithDiscoveredPeripheral:peripheral];
[peripheral setCoreBluetoothManager:self];
```

Per your comment, you could write your init method with something like this:

```
-(id)initWithDiscoveredPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self.cbPeripheral = peripheral; //where cbPeripheral is a property of this class to store the real CBPeripheral
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What would sit in this init method? I was thinking about that but got confused as to how I would init up the subclass with a CBPeripheral.

Comment: Check out my edit. That's a quick example of an init method you could write. Just wrote it on the fly though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In my subclass I don't have a property of cbPeripheral as this is why I want to subclass so all the CBPeripheral methods could be called on my SCPCBPeripheral. Without going through each property of the CBPeripheral is there a way to init my subclass with all the properties of the CBPeripheral passed in?

Comment: Instead of making it a subclass of CBPeripheral, you could just make a wrapper class that extends NSObject and implements the CBPeripheralDelegate Protocol and store the CBPeripheral in there. Or you could do something like what Josh Caswell said, and make a category. That would also work well.

Comment: I have decided not to subclass it as all I wanted to do was allow the user to write [peripheral connect] rather than getting the central manager to do it. Thanks though guys